# SpringBoot Hypermedia without HATEOAS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, hypermedia

My client don’t want to use HATEOAS library for some reason. Or there any other maven dependency alternative to HATEOAS?

I searched a lot but didn’t find any. Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

I did the same kind of research recently to see if we could implement hypermedia endpoints with Quarkus.

My conclusion was that there was not a single serious alternative to Spring Hateoas in the java ecosystem.

Spring Hateoas is **the** killer library that keeps us loyal to the Spring ecosystem.